# Latop won't boot from CD/DVD when HD is attached. BIOS order checked

Tags: boot, bios, laptop

My laptop, an older Toshiba A100-250, won't boot from a CD or DVD when the HD is attached.

I tried everything I can think of:

- Update the BIOS
- Reset BIOS to default values
- Change boot order in BIOS
- Press F12 during startup to select the 'CD/DVD' as the boot device

Despite all efforts, it still won't boot from a bootable CD or DVD.

If I detach the HD (sata) all is working fine. So the CD/DVD reader is ok and the media is bootable.

As a last resort, I tried disconnecting the HD during startup and reconnect it when the laptop is booting from the CD (bad practice, I know). This resulted in Windows seeing the HD but refuses to install to it because it was not detected in BIOS.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this on a basic search, it seems that you need to press and hold "c" during startup to get that model of Toshiba to boot from CD.

Ref:
http://forums.computers.toshiba-europe.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=50627

Comment: Unbelievable, but pressing "c" really worked! You don't want to know how many hours I wasted googling and trying to boot from cd. It used to work normally, but somehow something changed. I updated the BIOS after the problems, not before, so that can't be it. Strange. Once again, thanks a million!

Comment: No problem, good luck with the rest of your build.